# ¿Como diferenciar e identificar a los hackers en las preguntas?

Tags: discusión, soporte

A pesar de ver esta pregunta [Error al clonar sitio web Kali linux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87331/error-al-clonar-sitio-web-kali-linux), me he preguntado:

1. ¿Como detectar y diferenciar a los [White Hat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker#Hacker_de_sombrero_blanco) - o [Black Hat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker#Hacker_de_sombrero_negro) - [Hackers](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker#Clasificaci.C3.B3n_de_los_hackers)?
2. ¿Como deberían formular las preguntas sin que se sospeche malas intenciones?
3. ¿Hay unas normas ya establecidas en SO*?

Comment: Puede ser hasta útil que pregunten en Stack Exchange. Al creador de Silk Road lo detuvieron en parte por los registros que dejó en SO: [The Dumb Mistake That Brought Down Silk Road's Drug-Dealing Empire](http://www.businessinsider.com/silk-road-stack-overflow-post-2013-10). Una de sus dos preguntas es [sobre Tor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15445285/1983854).

Comment: Discusión relacionada en SO: [Should questions about programming viruses and malware be allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262749/1983854).

Comment: Si necesitas preguntar aca, de hacker no tienes nada...

Comment: @gbianchi - ???

Comment: es como preguntar: como protejo mi codigo pq es genial y a nadie se le ocurrio antes.. si tenes que preguntar, entonces te aseguro que de genial no tiene nada...

Comment: @gbianchi - Ah ok... ya pero habrá preguntas.... sean genial o no...

Comment: si pregunta, es inofensivo... te lo aseguro..

Comment: Eso es muy personal, ¿no? Si tu sentido de la moral te impide contestar una pregunta de lo que tu consideras un _hacker_ (por poner un ejemplo de una conducta dictada por la moral), debes tener alguna brújula moral que te norte sobre si una pregunta es, en tu opinión, de lo que tu llamas un hacker. Por eso digo que es personal, tanto la conducta como las acciones que se tomen o los aspectos que se usan para _detectar_ esas preguntas.

Comment: ¿Meterías en el saco de los black hat a los usuarios con preguntas del tipo "tengo esta versión de prueba de un código que es de pago, cómo hago para quitar marcas de agua/copyright/etc"? que de esas hay unas cuantas

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - Si leemos la definición del [Black Hat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker#Hacker_de_sombrero_negro)... _también conocidos como [crackers](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_(seguridad_inform%C3%A1tica))_ ... ahora queda decidir... :)

Comment: Teóricamente no, claro. Pero como parece un asunto de malas intenciones más que de ser un cracker en sí, estaría hablando de usar cosas de pago sin pagar, que parece poco moral/ético (aunque supongo que depende del punto de vista)

Answer (score 6):

No se hace distinción de los mismos. De hecho, todo el contenido publicado en Stack Exchange está bajo CC-BY-SA que no difiere mucho respecto a Dominio Público.

No hay restricciones sobre el contenido, todo lo publicado puede usarse para cualquier cometido sin garantía alguna. Así que en términos de Stack Exchange un *white hat* y un *black hat* no difieren en lo absoluto siempre y cuando sus preguntas sean objetivas, se ajusten a las reglas de Stack Exchange y las reglas de la comunidad (Stack Overflow en español).

Por ejemplo la pregunta expuesta, se podría reformular a 
*¿Cómo realizar copias estáticas del contenido (dinámico) de un sitio web?*, el cuál no difiere en nada a *Clonar* un sitio. Hay una entidad que lo hace para preservar el contenido de la web https://web.archive.org/. No obstante, alguien más podría usar la misma metodología para otros fines (secuestro de identidad, etc), así que ambos casos son caras de la misma moneda.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner alguna referencia de **CC-BY-SA**? Esto para investigar un poco más al respecto y para que la pregunta quede más completa ;)

Comment: @Flxtr al final de la página, en el mero fondo, está esta leyenda: _"site design / logo © 2017 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under
[cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)
with
[attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)"_ que corresponde a los [términos del servicio](https://stackexchange.com/legal) que aceptamos los usuarios al registrarnos en el sitio.

Comment: @toledano !Muchas gracias! ;)

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Como detectar y diferenciar a los White Hat - o Black Hat - Hackers?

En general no puedes. A toda pregunta por muy maliciosa que parezca se le puede añadir "Estoy ejecutando esto en un entorno aislado con el propósito de estudiar estos vectores de ataque para mejorar la protección de tal y tal..."
Las discusiones **públicas** sobre como crear malware ayudan a defenderse de ese malware. Las peligrosas son las privadas, pero esas no las verás en SO puesto que es un medio público.
Detectar a los Black Hat es trabajo de la policía. Mejor no meternos ahí. Ni tenemos los medios ni los conocimientos ni la autoridad apropiada.

> ¿Como deberían formular las preguntas sin que se sospeche malas intenciones?

No te preocupes por las intenciones de quien pregunta. Supón que son las mejores.

> ¿Hay unas normas ya establecidas en SO*?

Tampoco es trabajo de SO ocuparse de los Black Hat. Y, considerando la respuesta a la primera pregunta, tiene poco sentido el poner normas para intentar evitarlos.
Lo que hace SO, como cualquier otro sitio que publica contenido de terceros sin revisarlo, es desentenderse de la responsabilidad de ese contenido hasta el máximo que le permite la ley. Ver en los [términos de servicio el punto 5 :  Warranty disclaimer](https://stackexchange.com/legal)

Dicho esto, sí que puede haber casos puntuales que podrían requerir de la intervención de un moderador:

- La publicación de una vulnerabilidad sin respetar un tiempo de [revelación responsable](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelaci%C3%B3n_responsable).
- Código malicioso muy específico que no es de utilidad general (típico para script-kiddies). Lo que no es de utilidad general se debe cerrar pero esto además debiera borrarse.
- Publicación de datos personales privados.

Comment: Muy bueno lo de _No te preocupes por las intenciones de quien pregunta. Supón que son las mejores_, me recuerda el lema de la Wikipedia [_Presume buena fe_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Presume_buena_fe).